# I want to change the onclick of a button using javascript, but it's not working

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Okay, so I'm trying to write a simple show/hide content button, but I want to show and hide the content using two different functions. Now it hides just fine, but it won't re-show.

```
<html>
 <head>
 <title>Test</title>

 <script type="text/javascript">
  function hidecontent(){
   document.getElementById("content").style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById("hidebutton").value = "+";
   document.getElementById("hidebutton").onclick = showcontent();
  }

  function showcontent(){
   document.getElementById("content").style.display = "block";
   document.getElementById("hidebutton").value = "-";
   document.getElementById("hidebutton").onclick = hidecontent();
  }
 </script>

 <style type="text/css">
  #content{
   border: 1px solid #003333;
   background-color: #000033;
   color: #ffffff;
   height: 500px;
   width: 500px;
   text-align: center;
   display: block;
  }

  #hidebutton{
   border: 1px solid #003333;
   background-color: #000033;
   color: #ffffff;
   padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
   margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  }
 </style>

 </head>

 <body>
  <form>
   <input id="hidebutton" type="button" value="-" onclick="hidecontent()" />
  </form>

  <?php
   echo '<div id="content">Hello world!</div>';
  ?>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The `hidecontent()` should be without ending braces eg `document.getElementById("hidebutton").onclick = hidecontent;`. That was the problem :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

do this

```
document.getElementById("hidebutton").onclick = hidecontent;
```

Comment: Actually, Sarfaz, it did. O__O

Comment: Shouldn't it be technically like: `document.getElementById("hidebutton").onclick`

Answer (score 3):

*No need for two functions*, you can do this too:

```
function show_hide(){
    var ds = document.getElementById("content");
    var btn = document.getElementById("hidebutton");

    if (ds.style.display === 'block'){
       ds.style.display = 'none';
       btn.value = '+';
    }
    else {
       ds.style.display = 'block';
       btn.value = '-';
    }
}
```

Later you can call the function like this:

```
var btn = document.getElementById("hidebutton");
btn.onclick = show_hide;
```

Comment: Damn, you beat me to it. Anyway, William, this style of coding is much better than having an onclick attribute on your button. Separate behavior from your markup.

Answer (score 2):

document.getElementById("hidebutton").onclick = **showcontent**; //remove ()

document.getElementById("hidebutton").onclick = **hidecontent**; //remove ()